# Ansible ping not working

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-template

Below is my host file `/etc/ansible/hosts`

```
root@ubuntu:/home/dasitha# cat /etc/ansible/hosts
[web]
10.0.0.112 ansible_user=root

[local]
127.0.0.1 ansible_user=root
```

When I execute `ansible all -m ping -vv` below error throws.

```
ansible 2.5.3
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 18:00:18) [GCC 4.8.2]
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
META: ran handlers

    10.0.0.112 | UNREACHABLE! => {
        "changed": false,
        "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Permission denied (publickey,password).\r\n",
        "unreachable": true
    }
    127.0.0.1 | UNREACHABLE! => {
        "changed": false,
        "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Permission denied (publickey,password).\r\n",
        "unreachable": true
    }
```

Comment: This is an ssh problem and not ansible problem. Are you able to ssh into 10.0.0.112 from you local machine `ssh root@10.0.0.112` ?

Comment: check sshd logs on the 2 machines. if you are lucky, you may see a clear error description by: `systemctl status sshd`

Comment: @tux  `ssh root@10.0.0.112
root@10.0.0.112's password:
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-31-generic i686)`it prompt for passwd. When i entered the password. works fine

Comment: @ilias-sp this is the only log entry I am getting `May 24 17:32:35 ubuntuClient sshd[2389]: Connection closed by 10.0.0.111 [preauth]`

Comment: @Daz ok, so its not an ssh issue (had to rule this out). writing a potential answer with output now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since the ssh works between the ansible controller and the remote machine(s), its probably due to ssh rejecting the login due to failed authentication ways. you probably haven't exchanged ssh keys for passwordless login, and with your command you didnt provide the password either.

To provide in ad-hoc commands, like the one you tried, the password, you pass the `--ask-pass` flag at the end:

```
[ilias@optima-ansible ~]$ ansible greenhat -m ping --ask-pass
SSH password: 
greenhat | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false, 
    "ping": "pong"
}
[ilias@optima-ansible ~]$
```

without flag:

```
[ilias@optima-ansible ~]$ ansible greenhat -m ping
greenhat | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ilias@greenhat: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).\r\n", 
    "unreachable": true
}
[ilias@optima-ansible ~]$
```

hope it helps

Comment: PS: if you have multiple hosts to manage, and some of them have different passwords, then the above approach is not ideal for you. i recommend exchanging ssh keys. perhaps [this](https://github.com/ilias-sp/ansible-setup-passwordless-ssh) would be useful to you.

Comment: yes, I have multiple logins. Can you guide me on this?

Comment: I have removed one host to do the initiate testing. But its ended up with something like below. `root@ubuntu:/home/dasitha# ansible greenhat -m ping --ask-pass
SSH password:
 [WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: greenhat

 [WARNING]: No hosts matched, nothing to do`

Comment: `greenhat` is a hostname from my environment, you should use `all` or any indidivual host from your environment :)

Comment: ops! My bad. This works fine. Thanks :) Could you please guide me on how to exchange keys between servers?

Comment: there are plenty of articles out there on this. if you want to use my playbook, there is adequate documentation to get you started.

Comment: Could u please share it over here? :)

Comment: i had added the link in 1st comment, its [here](https://github.com/ilias-sp/ansible-setup-passwordless-ssh).

Answer (score 0):

Ansible assumes you’re using passwordless (key-based) login for SSH. If you insist on using passwords, add the `--ask-pass ( -k )` flag to Ansible commands (you may also need to install the `sshpass` package for this to work).

```
$ sudo apt-get install sshpass
ansible server-group -m ping -k -u username
SSH password:
```